# Share multiple start & end times of a YouTube video using <embed>

Tags: youtube, embed

I understand that it is quite simple to use start/end times in seconds to show a part of a YouTube video using embed, but how can I present multiple segments of a video as one? For example, If I have video A, I would like to show seconds 10-20 and then 45-55, using embed code.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can probably do this using the [iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), but this is beyond the scope of this forum - try Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

**You can not**.

You just have to **use the embed code again** in order to show the second part. You simply cannot have the video skipping a part and then continuing to another. This would be as if you edit the video, something not possible when just viewing it.